# Calling class method in swift

Tags: ios, class, swift, methods

I created a little program that takes in a persons name, gender and arena points and from that prints a message out depending on what the users gender / rating is.

Everything is fine until I call my method, I can see that kemkoi has received the values: `"kemkoi", "male" and "2500"` but whenever I call my method it just shows `"()"`

Here's the code:

```
class Player {
    var name : String
    var gender : String
    var arenaPoints : Int

    // method
    func getPlayerStats() {

        if(gender != "male" || gender != "female") {
            println("Please choose a gender!")
        } else if(arenaPoints < 2000) {
            println("Seems like you're too unexperienced \(arenaPoints) rating is not enough, come back when you have over 2.2k!")
        } else {
            println("Hello, \(name). You've chosen to play as a \(gender) and your arena points are equal to: \(arenaPoints)")
        }
    }

    // initializer
    init(name : String, gender : String, arenaPoints : Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.arenaPoints = arenaPoints
    }

}

var kemkoi = Player(name: "kemkoi", gender: "male", arenaPoints: 2500)

println( kemkoi.getPlayerStats() )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `println( kemkoi.getPlayerStats() )` you are printing the result of `kemkoi.getPlayerStats()`, which is nil.

Try simply calling `kemkoi.getPlayersStats()`

---

Also note that the method will always output `Please choose a gender!` because you're doing an OR, you should use an AND instead:

```
if(gender != "male" && gender != "female")
```

Comment: Wow, I'm actually that stupid. I don't know what I was thinking. Thank you! Also the if statement should be a '&&' and not a '||'.